# Checking if a list element is inside another list if so, substitute every element inside the base list

Tags: python

So I currently have a bunch of mocks list such as this one. Sample:

```
l = ['a','a','c','d']
l2 = ['c','b','b','d']
l3 = ['c','b','b','d','x','z']
l4 = ['a','c','a','a']
```

What I want to do is check if any of the values inside each of these lists, is equal to any of the values inside another list.

```
target_l = ['a','b']
```

If so i want to change every element inside these lists into the matched element.

Wanted result:

```
l = ['a','a','a','a']
l2 = ['b','b','b','b']
l3 = ['b','b','b','b','b','b']
l4 = ['a','a','a','a']
```

Comment: What if a list contains both `'a'` and `'b'`?

Comment: You asked a similar but different question earlier today, which got an answer... doesn't that give you any idea to have an attempt? What did you try?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark That wont happen i made sure of it

Comment: @trincot Unfurtunately, no i misphrased that question and the given solution was not exactly what i wanted. So i just did another to strike more on my personal issue. If needed i can delete the first one

Comment: I know it was different, but surely it showed you how to loop and overwrite a list with the same values... I would expect some effort in reusing those elements in a new attempt.

Comment: Yes you are in the right in that matter i should put a little more effort. I will keep that in mind, next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to loop over all of the possible targets. When you see a match, replace all the elements and `break`:

```py
for lst in [l, l2, l3, l4]:
    for target in target_l:
        if target in lst:
            lst[:] = [target] * len(lst)
            break

print(l, l2, l3, l4, sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```py
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it for `l`:

```py
for e in target_l:
    if e in l:
        l = [e]*len(l)
        break
```